# Azure DevOps generate an Artifact ID for a Pull Request

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

The Azure DevOps API article [Evaluations - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/evaluations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) describe how to receive a list of all the policy evaluation statuses for a specific pull request.

To call

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/policy/evaluations?artifactId={artifactId}&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

you need the `artifactId` for the request. The `artifactId` identify a pull request and it could be a part of the response from the [Pull Requests - Get Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). But it isn't, the `artifactId?` is empty.

Therefore, I think, the Author of the article add the following part:

> Evaluations are retrieved using an artifact ID which uniquely identifies the pull request. To generate an artifact ID for a pull request, use this template:
>
> `vstfs:///CodeReview/CodeReviewId/{projectId}/{pullRequestId}`

What should I do with this template? Is there an example? I do not understand this part and don't know what to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The description in the document means the value `artifact ID` is in below format:

`vstfs:///CodeReview/CodeReviewId/{projectId}/{pullRequestId}`

So you can use the template like below:

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/policy/evaluations?artifactId=vstfs:///CodeReview/CodeReviewId/{projectId}/{pullRequestId}&api-version=6.1-preview.1`

See below example in powershell:

```
$pat = "36w.......f65q"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProj/_apis/policy/evaluations?artifactId=vstfs:///CodeReview/CodeReviewId/39-...e13f/148&api-version=6.1-preview.1"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method Get
```