# Get the status of a pull request's checks

Tags: azure-devops

How can I programmatically get the following information? (1 required check)

[image: One required check]

I've looked at the response for [getting a Pull Request by Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-request-by-id?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) but there's nothing in there from what I can see.  I've tried [getting a Pull Request Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-statuses/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) but that just returns an empty array.

Comment: Does the List command return anything for that PR? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-statuses/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

Comment: I tested myself, and I don't think there's any way to do what you're trying to achieve here. Pull request status API only returns custom statuses but not required checks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it by retrieving a list of all the policy evaluation statuses for a specific pull request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/evaluations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

Comment: Also important to note - this is how you generate an artifact ID:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66114604/azure-devops-generate-an-artifact-id-for-a-pull-request

Comment: Very useful! One note, I needed the "followup" checks that appear in the UI - like releases triggered by the builds defined in the policy - and that doesn't show up in this API, only in the PR Statuses API. The result of both appears to match the AzDO UI.